# ListView + textview below layout problems

Tags: android, android-layout

So I've got this layout scenario that I havent found any desirable solution for. I've made a paint of it, i hope it's understandable.

[image]

Right now my ListView is always above the LinearLayout at the bottom. When the ListView has few items, the TextView is just below and it looks fine. However when it has many items, it crushes the TextView in between, which should always be there no matter what, between the LW and bottom container.

Could anyone give me a xml example that achieves just this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the `ListView` inside a `LinearLayout` and set weights to this `Linearlayout`, the `TextView` and the bottom `LinearLayout`. (You have to wrap the ListView inside a `LinearLayout` because you can't apply weights to a `ListView`).

Comment: This worked out fine. I was using a relativelayout as a root which gave me problems

Answer (score -1):

If I don't missundestand you, You try to create a `ListView` such as `wrap_content`? and the `TextView` is always below the `ListView`? If i'm not wrong, so, this is what you need:

```
 <LinearLayout // Your list view and TextView in a same linear layout
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp" // With this specific height, your TextView will
                                  // always in this range!
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="91dp"
        //layout_gravity = "right"?? I'm not sure, you should make it right alignment 
    />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout /> // This is your linear layout at the Bottom, 2 Lineary layout is 
                 // putted in a Relative layout
```

The layout above give you a ListView at the top, and the TextView is below, the LinearLayout at the Bottom. Try it out!!

Comment: You **can't** limit the height of a ListView. You have to wrap it inside a LinearLayout.

Comment: @Ahmad: yep! I know, but for me, the code above worked well! Have you ever try it?